# antipodal map $\alpha: S^m \rightarrow S^m$

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Fix $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Then antipodal map $\alpha: S^m \rightarrow S^m$ is defined by
$$S\in (x_1,x_2,...,x_{m+1})) \mapsto (-x_1,-x_2,...,-x_{m+1}).$$
$(a)$ Prove that the antipodal map  $\alpha: S^m \rightarrow S^m$ is smoothly homotopic to the identity map id:$S^m \rightarrow S^m$ whenever $m$ is odd.

$(b)$ Is $\alpha$ smoothly homotopic to id if $m$ is even? Explain

Any type of help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This map appears to be from the $m$ sphere to itself, but in the question and body you say they are two different dimensions. That said, you can give a proof using the degree of the map.

Comment: There is a typo. I will fix it thanks for noticing! @AlfredYerger

Answer (score 0):

For part a), can you figure out a smooth homotopy in 2-dimensions for $S^1$? Once  you figure out the homotopy you should be able to write down an explicit equation for it, and then it's not too hard to generalize it to $S^{2n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

If you need more of a hint:

> Take the coordinates in pairs.

For part b), you can use degree of a map, as a commenter has already noted.

Comment: For part a.... 

Maybe we can think of $S^1$ as the set of complex numbers mod 1? Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can totally think of $S^1$ that way -- and it actually makes the formulas easier to write.